# Ctrl-space not getting through ssh

Tags: ssh, terminal, windows

I am on windows 8 using GIT bash to access a remote server via `ssh`. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in emacs running locally in console (`emacs -nw`), everything works as expected. However, when going over `ssh`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> simply inserts a space, while other commands like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> work fine.

Why doesn't <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> get through? I have considered switching to a different terminal, but I am also curious as to why this is happening.

Comment: Why do you think Ctrl+Space is actually send as such? It might not be 'getting through' because it is sent as a simple space.

Comment: At some point in the chain (my keyboard to the process on the remote server) The sequence `Ctrl`+`Space` is getting transformed into just `Space`, and I'm fairly sure it's  the fault of ssh, since no such transformation occurs before ssh is in the chain

Comment: I assumed that with locally you meant when using a keyboard connected to your remote server. If you suspect ssh, you could try and setup telnet and see if that doesn't have the problem if you go with telnet over a port forwarded with ssh (telnet in itself is not secure as your password could be spied). An ssh tunnel will **not** filter an that out of the telnet session.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running things through the windows "shell" (DOS box, whatever) -- from a command line, it's because the terminal doesn't have a special map for `ctrl-space`.  An actual windows ssh client (`putty`, `securecrt`, etc.) handles the keyboard mapping itself, and will do what I assume you want done (send a `null`.)

Comment: using putty has worked, but I still don't know why ssh in windows command line doesn't work.

Comment: This is because putty set it's own keybindings, while ssh depend heavily on the running shell (eg: bash) for that (see `inputrc` for keybinding on the commandline) @Shelvacu

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SPACE</kbd>

Is actually the same as

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>@</kbd>

I've had situations when space didn't work and then used @ which did, however less convenient to type.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible, you are running an implementation of zssh?  According to the man page, Ctrl-Space is an escape sequence within a zssh session.

> **zssh behaves as an usual ssh session until the escape sequence is depressed** ( default is ^@ which can
>          be produced by pressing **C-space**, or C-2, or C-` ), which enables file transfer mode. A new prompt  is
>          then displayed, and commands can be executed locally to initiate file transfers (among other things).
>          It roughly behaves as a local shell  featuring  line  edition,  history  and  completion  (thanks  to
>          libreadline), globbing, and escape characters ( " ' and \ ).